# Dynamic Programming Recurrence to Solution

Tags: python, c++, c, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the weighted interval scheduling problem. Basically, I came up with the following recurrence to obtain the length of the optimum solution:

```
optimum[i] = max(duration(intervals[i]) + opt[prior[i]], opt[i - 1])
```

where prior[i] = the latest non-overlapping schedule that finishes before current interval starts.

The recurrence works well and I get the correct solution. However, I want to get the actual schedule and not just the length. How can I do that? I tried by starting from the largest p[i] value and following the pointer until I reach None / -1 / Null but that doesn't always work. I assume I need to keep track of which intervals to keep and which to discard as I solve the recurrence above. I tried by doing something like:

```
if (duration(intervals[i]) + optimum[prior[i]] >= optimum[i - 1]) {
  optimum[i] = duration(intervals[i]) + optimum[p[i]];
  retain[i] = true;
}
else {
  optimum[i] = optimum[i - 1];
  retain[i] = false;
  retain[i - 1] = true;
}
```

But this didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prior[i]` as well as `optimum[i]` to construct the path. Concretely, you start from the `i` with the optimal solution. Then the path can be got as follows.

```
queue<int> path;
int st = i;
while (st > 0) {
  if (op[st] == op[st-1]) st = st -1;
  else {
    path.push(st);
    st = prior[st];
  }
}
pop each item from queue<int> path, you get the intervals you selected.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I'm stuck at an infinite loop because st gets stuck at a certain value.

Comment: @PennyMahar Note the boundary index. Such as, the index starts from `1` or `0`, `prior[0]` should be -1 and so on. Also, you should make sure that `prior[i]` is strictly less than `i`.

Comment: I just double checked all indices and prior[0] to be -1 but it's not working. Also, should it be `st = prior[st];` above?

Comment: @PennyMahar Yes, it should be `st = prior[st]`. I will update it. Will it be okay?

Comment: Thank you! Now the loop is working fine and it is giving correct answer except in cases where the highest OPT value is shared by two or more timeslots. Why do we just go to the lower timeslot if that happens? What if the duration of current timeslot is larger than the previous timeslot?

Comment: @PennyMahar Have you sorted the timeslots by the increasing order of the end time in each timeslot?

Comment: Yes I have. I sort the timeslots first thing in the method.

Comment: @PennyMahar I think it should handle that case. Would you please send me your code?

Comment: Here is the Request class. Sorry for missing it earlier.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0af24c78a469fe33288a

Comment: @PennyMahar In schedule.py, line 63:  `for j in opt`; here j should from `0` to `len(intervals)`.

Comment: So you mean it should be `for j in range(len(intervals) + 1):`? That still didn't work. :/